# Initializing the Front Controller, what's the difference between these two

Tags: php, zend-framework, bootstrapping

I'm looking at some of the code I've written for Zend over the past 2 months and I see some inconsistency (because I'm a beginner) in initializing the front controller.

I see that sometimes I've done this

```
$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
```

and other times I've done this

```
$this->bootstrap('FrontController');
$frontController = $this->getResource('FrontController');
```

Not sure what I was thinking. I guess I was probably following examples. Anyone knows if there's any real difference between these two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One is a call to a Singleton object, which can be fetched from anywhere. The other is a call to the application bootstrapper, to retrieve a resource called 'FrontController'.

In theory, the resource called 'FrontController' could be anything that was assigned to the bootstrap with that name, such as a custom front controller implementation, if you didn't care to use Zend's.

In practice, they both retrieve the `Zend_Controller_Front` instance.

Comment: The front controller is always a singleton in Zend. Even when using the application bootstrapper, the resource will call it using `getInstance`. See `Zend_Application_Resource_Frontcontroller::getFrontController`.

Comment: @netcode, I understand it's a singleton. A clearer way to ask my question is: do singletons need to be initialized, or the getInstance takes care of initializing the instance if it's null.

Comment: In this case, `getInstance` takes care of initializing the instance if it's null. But in general, not necessarily. The singleton pattern itself does not define if the instance must be initialized on first use automatically. However, the practice of doing it is commonly called a **lazy-loaded singleton** or **Initialization on Demand Holder** pattern.

Answer (score 2):

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
```

The first method is a direct call to **Zend_Controller_Front**.

```
$this->bootstrap('FrontController');
$frontController = $this->getResource('FrontController');
```

The second method uses **Zend_Application** with **Zend_Application_Bootstrap_ResourceBootstrapper**. When initializing Zend_Application, it registers *FrontController* resource, which is then initialized with the `$this->bootstrap` call in your bootstrap file.

While the latter method will require both Zend_Application and Zend_Controller, the first method only depends on Zend_Controller.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is two of the same kind ;-)